# How to write into many2many field and display in UI?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

```
merged_beneficiary_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'openg2p.beneficiary',
        'merged_beneficiary_rel',
        'retained_id',
        'merged_id',
        string="Merged Duplicates",
        index=True,
        context={'active_test': False},
        help="Duplicate records that have been merged with this."
             " Primary function is to allow to reference of merged records "
    )
```

I want to write into this many2many field and show some specific fields(maybe firstname or lastname) of merged_id in the odoo UI.The data i have is the beneficiary record,id which will be retained and merged id.

Answer (score 0):

This works for x2many fields when you want to show specific fields you:
First put the tag field for ×2many field with starting tag:

```
<field name="x2many_field_name>
</field>
```

Now you add the tree tag inside the field to make specific list for this specific field:

```
<field name="x2many_field_name>
    <tree>
        <!-- here you make a list view for x2many field's model so it's as you're inside the x2many field's model -->
         <!-- specific fields you want to show here -->
    </tree>
</field>
```

The final code looks like this:

```
 <field name="merged_beneficiary_ids">
     <tree>
         <!-- your fields here -->
         <field name="firstname" />
     </tree>
 </field>
```

To add an existing record to the set:

```
self.write({'merged_beneficiary_ids' : (4, id, 0)
})
```

please check the documentation for operations on x2many field because Odoo deals with it in a special way.
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.write

Comment: yes this is correct;but i wanted to know how to add data into this 'merged_beneficiary_ids' many2many field using self.write()